# Software for ML/NLP/DM laboratory

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, software

suppose you might buy some software to be used in a ML/NLP/DM laboratory. What software package would you ask for? Let's say: MATLAB (with some toolboxes), SPSS, and what else?

I know that there is a lot of free software one can use like R, Weka, Rapidminer, python packages, and so on. However, the above question targets commercial software.

Thanks.

Comment: If your organization simply needs commercial support, as opposed to say, believing that commercial software is inherently better than open source, then you should consider that R and Python both have nice commercial distributions. See Revolution Analytics for R. For Python, see Enthought, Rogue Wave Software, and ActiveState.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in doing large-scale machine learning, at some point you will probably have to deal with large optimisation problems. In this case, the standard optimisation routines in the optimisation toolbox of matlab (`linprog`, `quadprog` etc) will probably not suffice). In this case a commercial optimisation package solver such as CPLEX would be worth a look. Other than that, for most other ML/NLP/DM tasks the open source community pretty much has it covered.